# panel size to window size (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I tried building my game, but I saw that the objects that were set on a panel didnt keep their position. If I click on max window size then the objects move away from their original position. How can I solve this? (see images for extra info)

[image]

[image]

Comment: its probably about your screen oriantation settings but you need to absolute same place use rect transform...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set ui elements' anchor position

For example my Restart button is in top-left place. When screen size change, it doesn't change position. To do this, click your ui object, click anhcor-presets section, press alt key and select a position which you want.

[image]

Also, Canvas scale may help you for resizing ui objects,when you change screen size

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the Canvas scale did the job. Sometimes the solution is that easy, you just have to know how to do it.